# (dblclick) has no effect

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm writing a todolist demo.I try to double click to edit the item ,but it has no effect and no error.

the code as below

```
<li *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index;"
            [ngClass]="{
              completed: todo.isDone,
              editing: currentEditing === todo
            }"
          >
            <div class="view">
                <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="todo.isDone" >
                <label (dblclick)="currentEditing = todo"> {{ todo.title }}</label>
                <button class="destroy" (click)="delete(i)"> </button>
            </div>
            <input class="edit" value="Create a TodoMVC template">
        </li>
```

but when i use `(click)`,the item can editing.

```
<label (click)="currentEditing = todo"> {{ todo.title }}</label>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is a link given below where dblclick work properly both for button and label on stackblitz. However, it works in different way as you have tried already. Please check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-double-click-bndehs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**Note:** Please Check DoubleClickDirective class inside double-click.directive.ts file and @HostListener

Comment: thanks, I found that after  I closed Google chrome toggle device toolbar, dblclick can work.

Comment: It's ok. There are more ways to do that task :).